# Jupyter Notebook to set environment variable from bash subprocess

Tags: python, bash, jupyter-notebook, environment-variables

In Jupyter Notebook, we can use

`% bash` to run cell with bash in a subprocess.

For example:

```sh
%%bash
export PROJECT=$(gcloud config list project --format "value(core.project)")
echo "Your current GCP Project Name is: "${PROJECT}
```

Can such exported environment variable be used in the next cell? What would this next cell's output be? (sorry I've run out of the allocated time in my GCP Project and cannot validate it myself)

```sh
%%bash
echo New $PROJECT
```

If not, then,

Is there any way to put the environment variable within bash subprocess to Jupyter Notebook's?

Comment: Exported variables are shared with children only. The parent can't access them, so they also aren't available to siblings (because each child gets a copy only of the environment variables owned by its direct parent).

Comment: In short: No, there exists no documented/supported interface that Jupyter Notebook can use to see what variables a subprocess it started has set. This isn't a Jupyter Notebook limitation -- it's true of _all_ processes in _all_ languages.

Comment: Ok, it's impossible then. thx

Comment: Have you considered running your `gcloud config` command from Python code? Once you have a Python variable, _that_ can be easily exported in the environment.

Comment: Yeah, that's an alternative way. I don't know Python or Jupyter Notebook, if doing from Python code is possible, then I can accept it as the answer too.

Comment: thx! I did have done some homework before asking, so would `%env PROJECT = subprocess.check_output(['gcloud', 'config', 'list', 'project', '--', 'value(core.project)']);` be OK as well?

Comment: I don't know -- I use Jupyter Notebook pretty rarely, so while I know bash and upstream Python well, I don't have a lot of knowledge of its extensions.

Comment: OK. Fair enough. Thanks!

Comment: (I'm assuming that you tested the answer to work before marking it accepted -- if it didn't work, that would probably mean that `%%bash` cells aren't started by the Python kernel; but that's a problem it should be possible to work around if necessary to do so).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't export variables from one bash cell to another (that isn't a child), but you *can* export from your Python parent process to bash.

```py
import os, subprocess

# set a Python variable 'project'
project = subprocess.check_output(['gcloud', 'config', 'list', 'project',
                                   '--format', 'value(core.project)'])

# Copy it to an environment variable 'PROJECT'
os.environ['PROJECT'] = project
```